# Angular 6 styles.js not applied to html

Tags: webpack, angular-material, node-sass

I'm working on legacy project was made in angular 6 with angular material...

I faced several problems while installing the modules, tried with different versions of node, and problems always occur after npm install, currently using node 12.22 (with/without package-lock )

Every time after npm install I have run other commands like

npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular

npm rebuild node-sass

After that, I can run ng serve and use the application.

The biggest problem is in relation to the style from material, all material components (input, dropdown, radios) are without any style

When running ng serve I look at source code of html and see a styles.js that contains all classes of material... but none of listed style in this file works.

I think thats a related webpack, sass or some module, but I cant figure out how to solve this issue, any help with this will be appreciated